# Javamail building email body - with data from multiple form fields - android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, jakarta-mail

Currently I am developing a phone app in android studio.

I have a simple contact form that has 9 total form fields.
ie...
Company Name
Emp. Name
Emp. Email
Emp. Phone
and so on.

The app works, the email is sent. However, where the problem is, is that when the email is sent... only the last form field data is passed through to the email body.

From what I can tell, all of the others are over written as the email body is created and data is pulled from what is being passed.

I tested this theory out by commenting out each form field and I would get the form field that i left un commented.

I know that there is a way to send attachements, etc. but all i want to do is pull all the data from the form fields into one variable and send that to the email body.

Has anyone experienced this? and or does anyone know javamail well enough to help out in moving this forward?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

to combat this issue and solve the problem.  I simply pulled all my form fields data into a single string variable.

````
                    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

                    String emailContent = "Realtor Company Name: " + rlCo.getText().toString() + "<br>" + "Realtor Name Making Request: " + rlNm.getText().toString() + "<BR>" + "Realtors Email: " + rlEml.getText().toString() + "<BR>" + "Realtors Phone: " + rlPh.getText().toString() + "<BR>" + "Clients Name: " + clNm.getText().toString() + "<br>" + "Clients Address: " + clAds.getText().toString() + "<br>" + "Closing Date: " + clsDte.getText().toString() + "<br>" + "Extra Notes: " + nts.getText().toString();

                    messageBodyPart.setContent(emailContent, "text/html");

                    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

                    message.setContent(multipart);

                    Transport.send(message);

                    System.out.println("Sent Message....");
                    Toast.makeText(LrServiceActivity.this, "Mail Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    loadingBar.dismiss(); ```

this worked for me.
````